# Separable elements of a finite abelian group

Tags: finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $\mathbf G$ be a finite abelian group, let $a, b \in \mathbf G$, and let $\langle a \rangle$ and $\langle b \rangle$ be the cyclic subgroups of $\mathbf G$ generated by $a$ and $b$ respectively.
We assume that $\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle = \{\mathbf 0\}$. 
Define $a$ and $b$ to be ***separable*** if there exist subgroups $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ of  $\mathbf G$ such that $\mathbf G = \mathbf A \oplus \mathbf B$,  $\langle a \rangle \subseteq \mathbf A$, and $\langle b \rangle \subseteq \mathbf B$. Can you find a necessary and sufficient condition under which $a$ and $b$ are separable?

**Example**. I think that, if $\mathbf G = \mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_{16}$,  $a = (2, 4)$, and $b = (1, 8)$, then $a$ and $b$ are not separable.